# Get selectedOptions on sl-select with Shoelace.style

Tags: shoelace

I have an `<sl-select>` element from Shoelace.style.

I have selected it in my script but unlike the native `<select>`, it doesn't appear to have a selectedOptions property.

Is there an alternative? or how can I get selectedOptions from it?

What options do I have here?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing by checking the `value` attribute on the sl-select component.

Here is a [demo](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vaW5kZXguanNcIj48L3NjcmlwdD5cbjwvaGVhZD5cbjxib2R5PlxuICA8c2wtc2VsZWN0IGlkPXNpbmdsZVNlbGVjdD5cbiAgICA8c2wtbWVudS1pdGVtIHZhbHVlPVwib3B0aW9uLTFcIj5PcHRpb24gMTwvc2wtbWVudS1pdGVtPlxuICAgIDxzbC1tZW51LWl0ZW0gdmFsdWU9XCJvcHRpb24tMlwiPk9wdGlvbiAyPC9zbC1tZW51LWl0ZW0-XG4gICAgPHNsLW1lbnUtaXRlbSB2YWx1ZT1cIm9wdGlvbi0zXCI-T3B0aW9uIDM8L3NsLW1lbnUtaXRlbT5cbiAgPC9zbC1zZWxlY3Q-XG4gIDxoND5TZWxlY3RlZCBvcHRpb246PC9oND5cbiAgPHAgaWQ9XCJzaW5nbGVTZWxlY3RlZERpc3BsYXlcIj48L3A-XG4gIFxuICA8c2wtc2VsZWN0IGlkPW11bHRpU2VsZWN0IG11bHRpcGxlPlxuICAgIDxzbC1tZW51LWl0ZW0gdmFsdWU9XCJvcHRpb24tMVwiPk9wdGlvbiAxPC9zbC1tZW51LWl0ZW0-XG4gICAgPHNsLW1lbnUtaXRlbSB2YWx1ZT1cIm9wdGlvbi0yXCI-T3B0aW9uIDI8L3NsLW1lbnUtaXRlbT5cbiAgICA8c2wtbWVudS1pdGVtIHZhbHVlPVwib3B0aW9uLTNcIj5PcHRpb24gMzwvc2wtbWVudS1pdGVtPlxuICA8L3NsLXNlbGVjdD5cbiAgPGg0PlNlbGVjdGVkIG9wdGlvbjo8L2g0PlxuICA8cCBpZD1cIm11bHRpU2VsZWN0ZWREaXNwbGF5XCI-PC9wPlxuPC9ib2R5PlxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoicGFja2FnZS5qc29uIiwiY29udGVudCI6IntcbiAgXCJkZXBlbmRlbmNpZXNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwibGl0XCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJAbGl0L3JlYWN0aXZlLWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMS4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjMuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtaHRtbFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiXG4gIH1cbn0iLCJoaWRkZW4iOnRydWV9XQ) of it working.